# JWT with multiple private/public keys pairs

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I am implementing something similar to : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys

Spring boot JWT application which generate and validate JWT token.
I will generate many public/private keys (I do not want to generate all tokens with one key. One keys pair will be generate token with shorter life time, second will generate longer...) 
I will create endpoint /keys with public keys. The question is : How to connect proper public key with private key in my application to validate it?

And the second one : How to generate keys like above (with fields like kty":"RSA","use":"sig", kid...) Is there any pattern to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to generate keys like above (with fields like  `"kty": "RSA"`, `"use": "sig"`, `"kid"`...) Is there any pattern to do it?

It's a standard called JSON Web Key (JWK), defined in the [RFC 7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517), which defines a data structure that represents a cryptographic key in JSON.

In Java, you can use [Nimbus JOSE + JWT](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt), which supports JWK with RSA keys.

---

> How to connect proper public key with private key in my application to validate it?

You can use the [`kid`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.4) header claim in your token: It's is an optional header claim which holds a key identifier, particularly useful when you have multiple keys to sign the tokens and you need to look up the right one to verify the signature.

Once a signed JWT is a JWS, consider the definition from the [RFC 7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515):

> [**4.1.4.  "kid" (Key ID) Header Parameter**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.4)
>
> The `kid` (key ID) Header Parameter is a hint indicating which key
> was used to secure the JWS.  This parameter allows originators to
> explicitly signal a change of key to recipients.  The structure of the
> `kid` value is unspecified.  Its value MUST be a case-sensitive
> string.  Use of this Header Parameter is OPTIONAL.
>
> When used with a JWK, the `kid` value is used to match a JWK `kid`
> parameter value.

Comment: Thanks for really exact reply! What is best practice to store keys on the server? I don`t have to have it on the remote repository

Comment: Thank, now I know how to store file safely. But I am not sure how to exact store keys. My idea -> generate (by keygen, openssl or sth like this) some keys pairs.So I will have file with some entries: 1. Entry type : PrivateKeyEntry , Certificate chain length: 3. Certificate[1]: Owner: owner, Issuer: issuer.. etc. So how to store it? Encode to base64 and store in txt file?

Comment: @michf It's beyond the scope of the original question. Please ask a new question.